# How to create AWS StateMachine Activity via serverless

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, serverless-framework, serverless, aws-step-functions

I'm trying to deploy Step Function, but I see no ways to define activity in serverless config.
    AWS docs https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-stepfunctions-activity.html saying that activity should be defined that way, but every time I do `sls deploy` I can't see new activity in step function console. Is it possible at all to create activity via serverless or I have to run script/create it manually?

```
Resources:
MyActivity:
    Type: "AWS::StepFunctions::Activity"
    Properties:
      Name: myActivity


stepFunctions:
  stateMachines:
    stepfunctest:
      events:
        - http:
            path: step
            method: get
      definition:
        Comment: "A sample application"
        StartAt: extract
        States:
          extract:
            Type: Task
            Resource: "arn:aws:state:#{AWS::Region}:#{AWS::AccountId}:activity:MyActivity"
            End: true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming you're uing the serverless plugin https://github.com/serverless-operations/serverless-step-functions. You can create the activity by adding the activity into the `stepFunction`

```
stepFuntions:
      activities:
        - myActivity
      stateMachines:
        stepfunctest:
          events:
            - http:
                path: step
                method: get
          definition:
            Comment: "A sample application"
            StartAt: extract
            States:
              extract:
                Type: Task
                Resource: "arn:aws:state:#{AWS::Region}:#{AWS::AccountId}:activity:MyActivity"
                End: true
```

Comment: thanks! but it is state with an S in the Resource arn: arn:aws:states:#{AWS::Region}:#{AWS::AccountId}:activity:MyActivity